# Blazor Nav Menu Sub Menu

Tags: html, css, blazor

I have created a menu item with a collapsible sub menu. When on the Home page the top level item **Home** is getting decorated with the active attribute, the expected behavior, and then the item is showing as active since I have the **href** set to nothing (href="") When the Index.razor page is showing the **Administration** menu item is set to active as well since the href is set to empty string as well.

What is the best way to have the **Administration** look like a menu item? Should I use a div in this case?

Is there a way to make the default active attribute not be assigned?

I think I'm missing some simple Blazor thing to make this behave like I want. Any help is much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Calculator/CalculationName">
                        <span class="oi oi-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> Calculation Set
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>

        <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
            <Authorized>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" @onclick="() => expandAdminSubMenu = !expandAdminSubMenu">
                        <span class="oi oi-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>Administration
                    </NavLink>
                    @if (expandAdminSubMenu)
                    {
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Administration/ClientList" Match=@NavLinkMatch.All>
                                <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span>Client List
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Administration/Client/-1" Match=@NavLinkMatch.All>
                                <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span>Client
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="https://www.example.com/contact-us/" target="_blank">
                <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contact Us
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code{
    private bool expandAdminSubMenu = false;
}
```

***CSS***

```
.sidebar .nav-item a.active {
    background-color: #3b34a8;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar .nav-item a:hover {
    background-color: #3b34a8;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `ActiveClass="@string.Empty"` - the ActiveClass is the parameter that controls what active class that navlink will get and it defaults to `active`, but you can set it to an empty string so that it renders nothing.

Option 2 = replace `NavLink` with a simple `<a>` tag - it won't get the active class.